# How can I properly escape the value of a .env variable that contains a dollar sign?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, escaping

In a `.env` file that I use in a `docker-compose.yml` file.

```
version: '3'
services:
  my_service:

    ...

    env_file:
      - src/.env

    ...
```

I've a variable set like this:

`APIKEY_SALT=$foo$foo$foo/foo/foofoofoo`

But `docker-compose` wrongly interprets that value:

> WARN[0000] The "foo" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.`

How can I escape it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wrap the variable in single quotes: `APIKEY_SALT='$foo$foo$foo/foo/foofoofoo'`

As mentioned here: https://deploy-preview-13474--docsdocker.netlify.app/compose/env-file/#syntax-rules

and here: https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/8607