# Docker-compose service restarting continuously with warnings about unset variables

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am encountering an issue with my Docker-compose setup where one of the services, specifically the `profiles` service, keeps restarting continuously. I'm seeing warnings in the logs related to unset variables, but I'm not sure if they are the root cause of the problem. Here's an overview of my `docker-compose.yml` configuration:

```
x-variables: &variables
  ENV_STAGE: local

services:
  profiles:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./compose/dev/web/Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./web/:/usr/src/web/
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    environment:
      <<: *variables
    env_file:
      - ./compose/dev/env/.env
      - ./compose/dev/env/.db.env
      - ./compose/dev/env/.data.env
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    restart: unless-stopped

  postgres:
    image: postgres:latest
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./compose/dev/db/pg.conf:/etc/postgresql/postgresql.conf
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=test
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password
      - POSTGRES_DB=test
      - PGDATA=/var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    command: postgres -c config_file=/etc/postgresql/postgresql.conf
    env_file:
      - compose/dev/env/.db.env
```

The `postgres` service seems to be running fine, but `profiles` keeps restarting.

The logs show warnings about unset variables like `"o58"`:

```
PS C:\Users\admin\profile> docker-compose logs --tail 50 --follow profiles
time="2024-02-25T12:17:28+02:00" level=warning msg="The \"o58\" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string."
time="2024-02-25T12:17:28+02:00" level=warning msg="The \"o58\" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string."
time="2024-02-25T12:17:28+02:00" level=warning msg="The \"o58\" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string."
PS C:\Users\admin\profile>
```

Could someone please assist me in troubleshooting this issue? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Where is `o58` defined (in one of the `.env` files?) and used?  Is the container actually exiting?  The Compose file mostly seems fine, it seems like the actual problem is likely to be in something that's not included in the question yet.

Comment: Actually, the only place where I found something like `o58` is here:



`.env`:

`SECRET_KEY=22+sg%5+##a=^-$o58(1q9(^r@cjl-p0r3m^x9@-#i=1qcs2y12asdwqz2341casdf%zx`



When I remove the `$` sign before `o58`, the log disappear, but it keeps restarting (not running).

Comment: So, only in the one of the `.env` files is this `o58`. And I am not sure if this is the problem.

Comment: [Compose `.env` files do variable interpolation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/env-file/#interpolation) and that's likely the problem.

Comment: Can you guide me how to fix it? :)

Sorry, if it is something easy! :)

I really appreciate your support!

Comment: Does [How can I properly escape the value of a .env variable that contains a dollar sign?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75322493/how-can-i-properly-escape-the-value-of-a-env-variable-that-contains-a-dollar-si) answer your question?  Putting the variable value inside single quotes `SECRET_KEY='22...-$o58(...zx'` seems like the easiest answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256977/discussion-between-donko-and-david-maze).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I properly escape the value of a .env variable that contains a dollar sign?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75322493/how-can-i-properly-escape-the-value-of-a-env-variable-that-contains-a-dollar-si)

Comment: @ErikMD, Actually, the log disappeared, but it doesn't solved my problem.

The application is restarting (not running), which is my main problem.

Comment: @Donko OK so the fix is not enough. I'm not sure your question is self-contained (in particular, if the bug comes from the service that involves a Dockerfile).

Comment: Three independent remarks anyway: 1. Avoid naming env\_files merely `".env"` (cf. [this long, old answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72105572)). 2. Test the outcome of your env\_files by running `docker compose config` and 3. double-check that the `volumes: [./web/:/usr/src/web/]` spec is needed (there may be a permission issue because of that, for example).

Comment: @ErikMD, thank you so much for your replies, but it is still restarting. :( :(

Comment: I tried to remove the `volumes: [./web/:/usr/src/web/]`, but it is still restarting.

Comment: @ErikMD, Can we jump on a chat? :)